# Null Propagation operator in Node.js

Tags: node.js, null

I need to do something similar to `bar = (foo == null) ? null : foo.bar`

Is *Null Propagation Operator* (`?.`) available in Node.js? If no, Is this a proposal for the newer version?

[Edit] To add more clarity, I want to avoid NPE when accessing `foo.bar` (when `foo` is not defined) and the expression should return a `null` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript has added support for this, It's called `Optional Chaining`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 2):

*Update based on below comment*:

The below code will evaluate to the value of foo if foo is falsey (null, undefined, false, empty string, etc), or to foo.bar if foo is not falsey. Like the || operator, the && operator also returns whatever it evaluates last. If foo is falsey, then it will abort evaluation and return the value of foo. If foo is not falsey, then it will continue and evaluate foo.bar and return whatever that is.

```
foo && foo.bar
```

*Original answer*:

You can accomplish this in Javascript using the **or operator, ||**

The **or operator** does not necessarily evaluate to a boolean. It returns the last argument that it evaluates the truthiness of.

So, building off of your example, the following code sets foo equal to foo.bar.

```
foo = null || foo.bar
```

And the following compares foo to foo.bar (I'm not sure if the double =s in your code was intentional or not. If it was intentional, then consider using triple =s instead)

```
foo === (null || foo.bar)
```

This concept is frequently used for setting default values. For example, a function that takes an **options** argument may do something like this.

```
options.start = options.start || 0;
options.color = options.color || "red";
options.length = options.length || 10;
```

Just be careful of one thing. In the last line of the above code, if options.length is 0, then it will be set to 10, because 0 evaluates to false. In that scenario, you probably want to do things the "old-fashioned" way:

```
options.length = options.length === undefined ? 10 : options.length;
```

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough with the question. I want to access `foo.bar` without an NPE. I'm expecting the expression to return `null` if `foo` is `null`

Comment: @SarathVS I think I know what you mean so I updated my answer, but I'm not certain because your code example is frankly a little confusing. ```null ? null : foo.bar``` will always evaluate to whatever ```foo.bar``` is, because null is a falsey value. So you could replace your code snippet with ```foo == foo.bar``` and it would be the same. If my update doesn't answer your question, could you please try to clarify that code?

Comment: looking for date of support for Null Propagation Operator in node js

Comment: search for Optional chaining

Answer (score 0):

```
const bar = foo && foo.bar;
```

This is called [Short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation), where second part (part after &&) is only evaluated if the first part is a [truthy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

Comment: looking for date of support for Null Propagation Operator in node js

Comment: search for Optional chaining